# JDBC statement query timeout is 0

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I did print the JDBC query timeout which is available at the statement level:

```
Statement statement=con.createStatement();

System.out.println(statement.getQueryTimeout()); // This prints 0
```

It prints 0. What does this mean? Does it mean that the query will wait indefinitely till it completes?

Comment: **Read the documentation!!!** The javadoc of [`getQueryTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getQueryTimeout--) says *"Returns the current query timeout limit in seconds; **zero means there is no limit**"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javadoc for [`Statement#getQueryTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getQueryTimeout()) mentions this regarding the return value:

> the current query timeout limit in seconds; zero means there is no limit

So we can interpret what you are seeing is that there is no set timeout for the statement to execute.

Note that this does *not* mean that your database connection does not have any timeout.  It does, and a statement taking too long will probably be dropped by the database.